# c# Call method for generic types

Tags: c#, generics

Idea is as follow:
I want to have mechanism of revesing item's value. Item can be bool, int, double. Every type should implement it's own logic of "reversing".

Logic is like that :

```
    public class Integers : IInterface
{
    public int Reverse(int value)
    {
        return -value;
    }
}

public class Bools : IInterface
{
    public bool Reverse(bool value)
    {
        return !value;
    }
}
```

I know that for generic's all classes must derive from sth common, so I created an interface called IInterface:

```
    public interface IInterface<T>
{
    T Reverse(T value);
}
```

Now In my code I want to run sth like that:

```
Reverse(1); //int - expect to return -1
Reverse(true); // bool - expect to return false
```

I am stuck, don't know howw to achieve that.

Comment: I would suggest implementing a `Reverse` extension method for each type. Then call `1.Reverse()` or `true.Reverse` or whatever. _Or just make a standard `static` method for each type and call it the way you have now. Either way - no need for the interface._

Comment: You are looking for overloaded methods (or extension methods), not for generic interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    T Reverse(T value);
}

public class Integers : IInterface<int>
{
    public int Reverse(int value)
    {
        return -value;
    }
}

public class Bools : IInterface<bool>
{
    public bool Reverse(bool value)
    {
        return !value;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Integers i = new Integers();
        Bools b = new Bools();

        Console.WriteLine(i.Reverse(5));
        Console.WriteLine(b.Reverse(true));
    }
}
```

Option Number 2:

```
public class ReverseClass
{
    const string INT_TYPE = "System.Int32";
    const string BOOL_TYPE = "System.Boolean";

    public Object Reverse(Object value)
    {
        string type = value.GetType().ToString();

        switch(type)
        {
            case INT_TYPE:
                return -(Int32)value;
            case BOOL_TYPE:
                return !(bool)value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReverseClass x = new ReverseClass();

        Console.WriteLine(x.Reverse(5));
        Console.WriteLine(x.Reverse(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: This strikes me as harder to understand than the extension method approach.

Comment: Is there other way - I don't want to call this on integers.Reverse() but make more "generic" like: x.Reverse(1); x.Reverse(false); Is that possible? x can be whatever

Comment: couple seconds i making you an example

Comment: i added option 2, try it

Answer (score 2):

Something tells me that wrapping all the primitive types in order to implement such methods is not a good idea, and in the long run you are gonna face unnecessary complexity. Why don't you use [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)? Example:

```
namespace MyNamepace
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Boolean b = true;
            Boolean b_rev = b.Reverse();
            Console.WriteLine(b); // True
            Console.WriteLine(b_rev); // False

            Int32 i = -20;
            Int32 i_rev = i.Reverse();
            Console.WriteLine(i); // -20
            Console.WriteLine(i_rev); // 20
        }
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static Boolean Reverse(this Boolean value)
        {
            return !value;
        }

        public static Int32 Reverse(this Int32 value)
        {
            return -value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I will have to say first that your approach defies the purpose of using interfaces and generic types. You are using a generic type interface but hardcoding the reverse mechanic, it doesn't really help you much, might as well hardcode them in a method or in extensions (like @mjwills suggested).

Anyway, I will still help you with the issue, your approach might be a way to learn.

Your `IInterface<T>` is good, but the classes implementing it aren't. They will have to specify the type used, like this:

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    T Reverse(T value);
}

public class Integers : IInterface<int>
{
    public int Reverse(int value)
    {
        return -value;
    }
}

public class Bools : IInterface<bool>
{
    public bool Reverse(bool value)
    {
        return !value;
    }
}
```

In order to use this, you'll have to create an instance of each class and use their respective `Reverse` method, like this:

```
var integers = new Integers();
Console.WriteLine(integers.Reverse(1)); // -1

var bools = new Bools();
Console.WriteLine(bools.Reverse(true)); // False
```

Comment: Is there other way - I don't want to call this on integers.Reverse() but make more "generic" like:
x.Reverse(1);
x.Reverse(false);

Is that possible? x can be whatever

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think that for this your solution is a bit not suitable:

I don't want to call this on `integers.Reverse()` but make more "generic" like: `x.Reverse(1); x.Reverse(false);` Is that possible? `x` can be whatever..
But I want to avoid `ExtensionMethods` way.

Comment: You shouldn't post this kind of things as anwers, use comment sections instead. Anyway... you could create a generic method with `where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible` constraint... but this risk to be a tricky path...

Comment: have an answer for you as an option 2

Comment: Tommaso's answer provides this. Call `ExtensionMethods.Reverse(1)` or `ExtensionMethods.Reverse(false)`.

Comment: I don't want extension emthod's way! But generic's